# Return 2 variables in swift

Tags: ios, swift, variables, return, uipickerviewdatasource

I'm a newbie developer, trying to return 2 variables but without any success. Here are what I have already tried:

1. I tried to put these 2 variables (I'm not sure if those are variables or they have different name) into the array and then call return, but the error was:

   > "cannot convert return expression of type [Int] to return type int"

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
       var typeAndStoreArray = [Int]()
       typeAndStoreArray.append(stores.count)
       typeAndStoreArray.append(types.count)
       return typeAndStoreArray
   }
   ```
2. I tried to put `stores.count` into variable called `sc` and `types.count` into variable called `tc`, but here as well I had an error

   ```
   func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
       let sn = stores.count
       let tn = types.count

       return (sn, tn)
   }
   ```

Comment: `-> Int` It needs to return only an `Int`. This is a classic `UIPickerViewDelegate` method, what are your trying to do exactly? Because it seems that you miss a concept on `UIPickerView`.

Comment: Yes, there's definitely some confusion. Why are you trying to return two values at once from a picker view delegate method that can only return one value at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to understand the functionality of this delegate method.

The method is called multiple times for each component. It passes the index of the component and expects to return the corresponding number of rows.

So if your `stores` array is component 0 and `types` is component 1 you have to write

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     if component == 0 {
        return stores.count
     } else {
        return types.count
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing picker view. To have two *wheels of values*, you need to return counts for each wheel separately. A component in picker view is like the wheel. So, to have the first wheel (component) displaying stores and then second wheel displaying types, you need to return counts separately like this

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if component == 0 {
        return stores.count
    } else
        return types.count
    }
}
```